# Traceback errors in KiCad

Tags: wxpython, kicad

[image]

I installed an external plugin in windows machine of  kicad 6.0.4 and 6.0.5 versions and used to run perfectly with no errors.But in kicad 6.0.6,it is throwing the below error.
wxpython version installed:4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.6
Anyhelp in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

As of wx 3.1.6 (which is now included in Windows builds of KiCad 6.0.6), the `SetBitmap` call requires a wxBitmapBundle parameter

This will need to be updated by your plugin provider